# Kentico smart search with custom web part

Tags: kentico

I have custom web part registered in Kentico web page and I would like to use Kentico smart search to search information from web part.

My custom web part contains grid view with following columns

```
Item Code
Item Name
Item Price
Mfg. Date
```

If user is going to enter "Laptops" in search box then system should search information based on Item Name.

Can anyone give me brief idea about Kentico smart search which satisfy above functionality?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the smart search index and set it to be the document crawler? In this case the crawler will index the HTML output of the pages - including the output of the web part.

Comment: Thank you John.
I have applied this solution but no luck

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how smart search operates.

Basically you'll use Smart search to index your database.

You can then use Kentico's Smart search API to filter a dataset to be used to bind into a repeater or datalist of some type.

The only thing I can suggest is consulting the Kentico documentation for your version of Kentico, specifically looking for smart search. If you included more information such as the Kentico version and the source of your data (documents, custom tables, etc) then someone may be able to give a clearer answer.